# Avoiding multiple API Calls in Rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to test a "scan" method that I have. Within this scan method, I make an API call (among other things).

How can I test this method without triggering unneeded API calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to just stub out the call to the API:

```
allow(thing).to receive(:action).and_return(response)
```

Another approach is to allow the API call to go through, but to intercept it and return a mock response using [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr). To do this you "record" a request and "play it back".

VCR is handy when you need to handle the the entire response in the test subject. Just run the test against the real API one time, then subsequent tests can use the VCR "cassette". OTOH this is slower than simply stubbing the call, especially if you only need to mock the status and not the entire response.

TL:DR, stub if you can, but don't hesitate to use VCR when it saves you work.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check that out

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be making API calls in your test environment. In order to prevent these calls, you should `stub` the method so that it return a `true` or `success` upon being called.